# asp.net web api - How to authenticate user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have successfully logged in from web api controller. But when I try to get Authorized data from MVC Controller it returns me 401 unauthorized. here is my web api login controller.

```
using crudaspangularjs.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

namespace crudaspangularjs.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api")]
    [Authorize]
    public class AuthController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseType(typeof(AdminLoginModel))]
        public IHttpActionResult Login(AdminLoginModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
                CrudAspAngularjsDbEntities2 db = new CrudAspAngularjsDbEntities2();
                Admin adminLoggedin = db.Admins.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Email==model.Email && x.Password == model.Password);
                if (adminLoggedin == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();

                }
                else
                {
                    var authUser = from admin in db.Admins
                                where admin.Email == adminLoggedin.Email
                                select new AdminLoginViewModel { Email = 
                                admin.Email, Name = admin.Name, RoleId = 
                                admin.RoleId, RoleName = admin.RoleName };
                    return Ok(authUser);

                }

        }
    }
}
```

here is the mvc controller.

```
using Rotativa;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using crudaspangularjs.Models;

namespace crudaspangularjs.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private CrudAspAngularjsDbEntities db = null;
        public UserController()
        {
            db = new CrudAspAngularjsDbEntities();
        }
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var user = db.Users.ToList();
            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        [Authorize]
        public JsonResult Details(int id)
        {

            var user = db.Users.Find(id);
            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(User user)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(null);
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Edit(User user)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(null);
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(null);
        }
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult PrintViewToPdf()
        {
            var report = new ActionAsPdf("Data") 
                 {
                    FileName = "ReportData.pdf",
                    PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4
                 };
            return report;
        }
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Data()
        {
            // ViewBag.user = db.Users.ToList();
            var user = db.Users.ToList();
            return View(user);
        }
    }
}
```

But everytime I perform an action it return 401 unauthorized. Looking for help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't see any code where you actually perform login. You check the credentials, yes, but login is where you (with help of some authentication API set user identity into (most commonly) a cookie, like:  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);

Comment: And you do not need [Authorize] attribute on each method if it's already set on the controller.

Comment: The problem is solved after configuring formsAuthentication as you told. Thank you. :)

Comment: Formatted as the answer. Don't hesitate to mark the question answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a user *authenticated* you have to perform a *sign in* operation.
What you do in your `Login` method is checking the credentials, but *sign in* is where you (with help of some authentication API) set user identity into (most commonly) a cookie, like:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ASP Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) as well. You can [Authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2) your users out of a box.